# Lower bound related to couples of disjoint two-element sets

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I have already asked this question at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/455668/136218), but without answers. I want to give it a try here, maybe somebody can answer or give interesting hints.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the family of all subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\} $ of size $2$. Let $\mathcal{F} = \{\mathcal{A}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{A}_n\}$ be a grouping of sets in $\mathcal{B}$ in such a way that every set belongs to exactly one of the families $\mathcal{A}_i, 1 \le i \le n$. It is not a partition because one or more of the $\mathcal{A}_i$ can be empty. It is explicitly required that $n$ is also the size of $\mathcal{F}$, it is not an error.

Let $\mathcal{F}_a = \{\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{F} : \exists B \in \mathcal{A} : a \in B\}$, i.e. the number of families that have $a$ as element of at least one of their sets.

We know that for a given $m \le n$, $\vert \mathcal{F}_x \vert \le m, 1 \le x \le n$.

Let $G = \{\{B,C\} : \exists \mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{F} : (B \in \mathcal{A}) \land (C \in \mathcal{A}) \land (B \cap C = \emptyset)\}$, i.e. the unordered couples of sets in $\mathcal{B}$ belonging to the same family and disjoint.

I would like to find a lower bound for $\vert G \vert$ over all possible groupings $\mathcal{F}$ as a function of $m$:

$$\vert G \vert \ge f(m)$$

I have a conjectured possible lower bound:

$$f(m) = \frac{\binom{n-m+1}{2}\binom{n-m-1}{2}}{2} \tag{1}$$

That value can be achieved with $\mathcal{A_1} = \{A \in Q: 1 \in A \}, \mathcal{A_2} = \{A \in Q, A \not\in \mathcal{A_1}: 2 \in A \}, \mathcal{A_3} = \{A \in Q, A \not\in \mathcal{A_1},\mathcal{A_2}: 3 \in A \},\ldots,\mathcal{A_{m-1}} = \{A \in Q, A \not\in \mathcal{A_1},\ldots,\mathcal{A_{m-2}}: m-1 \in A \}, \mathcal{A_m}$ containing the remaining sets, $\mathcal{A_{m+1}}=\cdots=\mathcal{A}_n =\emptyset$. For example, for $n=5$, $m=2$, we have $\mathcal{A_1} =\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\}\}$, $\mathcal{A_2} =\{\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\}\}$, $\mathcal{A_3} = \mathcal{A_4} = \mathcal{A_5} = \emptyset$, and $f(m)=f(2)=3$.

Is it possible to prove that $(1)$ is actually a lower bound or find another one?